# Difference between vectors,vertex and faces?

Tags: c++, winapi, math, opengl

I always find this difficult to understand as it seems all very theoretical.

```
glVertex(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glVertex(0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
glVertex(-1.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);
glVertex(-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```

that's one face of a cube in openGL.

I open up a obj file and the faces are stored like this:

```
f 61 67 52
f 50 66 49
```

etc etc

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: A vertex is simply one of the 3 points used to define a triangle. A face is a polygon produced by lining up multiple triangles. E.g. each of your cube's sides is a face, each face being produced by 2 triangles. Those two triangles have 4 distinct vertices (2 common vertices, and one unique one each)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing here but you seem to be confused about the format of the obj file.

`f 61 67 52` is actually really simple: It specifies that the vertices #61, #67, and #52 form a triangle (a face) in 3D space.

I will also point out that your referencing a sequence of four OpenGL Immediate Mode `glVertex` calls as "one face of a cube" is not a particularly good description of what that code actually does or represents. The code itself specifies four 3D vertices and that is the only information being specified. The concept of a face, or for that matter a triangle (the building block of 3D graphics), is not the same thing as the specification of vertices.

There are a few reasons that you don't see a lot of people using the geometric term "face" in 3D Graphics, its usage in .obj files being an exception. It is because the graphics hardware is designed to operate on triangles: If you wanted to make a pentagonal face you'd really be constructing it out of 3 or more triangles. I couldn't tell you why it is `f 61 67 52` rather than `t 61 67 52` as that'd make more sense. Note that if you take four non-coplanar vertices you cannot make a flat geometric face out of it! This is why it is okay to refer to a triangle as a face: Any 3 points are coplanar.

Answer (score 1):

- Vector is or can be thought of as a direction (target position
  coordinates - your current position coordinates would tell you the
  direction you need to go)  and/or simply a list of coordinates in
  particular n-dimensional space e.g. (1, 0, 0) in 3-D (x, y, z).
- Vertex is a point in a space, which could be described by a Vector (a
  list of coordinates (x, y, z)).
- Face is a convex space which is made by connecting at least 3
  vertices one by one usually anti-clockwise (that would make a
  triangle). Direction is important to understand which side the face
  would be facing. Other side would not be rendered.

Each face in a mesh usually has a number, which acts as an index and a normal vector, which shows the direction where is the rendered side of this particular face (simply from where to look to see the texture which might be mapped onto this face). This all depends on a particular format how mesh is stored (obj is only one of several formats, proprietary programs usually have their own closed format).

Comment: Actually a vector is a element of a vector space. Anything can be a vector. A number, colors, chairs, quantum states, etc. A vertex **is not a point in space!!!** A vertex is a vector consisting of a lot of attributes that make up a vertex; often it is the combination of position, normal, texture coordinates and a few other attributes. But a vertex **is not** just the position!

Comment: @These are not essential attributes of a Vertex. When you define a vertex, you define its coordinates. Everything else is secondary. In mathematical sense you can describe Vector as a group of attributes, but in CG sense they have very specific meaning (that is transforming object from one position in space into the other).

Comment: When you define a vertex you **do not** define its coordinates. It's perfectly possible to supply OpenGL with vertex attributes that contain *no* position, and the position is generated by a vertex shader on the fly from the given generic vertex attributes. In fact it is possible to supply empty vertex vectors and have the vertex shader generate a position solely from the submission index. Please understand this: **A vertex is not a position, _and_ a position is not a neccesary vertex attribute!**

Comment: And it doesn't matter if we talk about CG or not. The purpose of a vertex is defining attributes of the corner of a planar-finite primitive. And the attributes of this corner can be given in an arbitrary vector space, which doesn't have to be spatial at all. The only requirement by OpenGL is, that the vertex attributes are convex in this vector space. Turning a subspace of the vertex vector space into position is what the transformation pipeline does. In fixed function OpenGL one attribute was reserved for position. In modern OpenGL everything is completely arbitrary and user configurable.

Comment: @datenwolf Yes, in broader sense you're right, but as it is mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28computer_graphics%29 A vertex (plural vertices) in computer graphics is a data structure that describes a point in 2D or 3D space. Display objects are composed of arrays of flat surfaces (typically triangles) and vertices define the **location** and other attributes of the corners of the surfaces.My: location is necessary attribute, whether provided/generated by the shader during tl pipeline or manually. In the end mesh can't exist without vertices and about which OP is asking about.

Comment: Well, this is a Wikipedia article and unfortunately Wikipedia is not always a reliable source and in some topics quite outdated or inaccurate. And more importantly the location of a point in space can be described by other things than just its position. Also the list of OpenGL built in vertex attributes is outdated and valid only for OpenGL versions *prior* to *OpenGL-3 core*. Modern OpenGL (OpenGL-3 core and above) no longer have built in vertex attributes at all.